# Making a collection out of nested object arrays in Backbone?

Tags: backbone.js

I was wondering if it is possible to make a collection out of a nested collection within my model data, my model contains an array of objects called `agents` and instead of pushing new agents directly to the model array I would like to handle these as their own collection, is this possible? Like do I make a collection then use the initialize to drill into the `this.model.get('agents')` or do I pass this into the new collection?

**Model data**:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name: "Greenwich",
  "location": "UK",
  "city": "London",
  "agents": [
    {
     "id": 3,
     "name": "James Coy"
    },
    {
      "id": 56,
      "name": "Steven Pajak"
    },
    {
      "id": 32,
      "name": "Terry Collins"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go from the tinest object to the largest. What I mean is that you model (Model Data)at the end should be a composition (or else I think you may review your data map).

So when you receive your data I would first populate the collection that handle agents then build the model passing name,location ..etc and in the init call the collection that handle agents.

For me the only reason you may/can have redundancy is that you are building higher data model from lower level (a composition of several small data entities).

So both solutions you explained are doable but the one that makes more sense to me is:

1. Set the agents collection
2. Build the higher "ModelData"(don't know its name... =)) getting the agents part from the agents collection in the init.

It's like your solution with the init but in the other way (from atomic part to composition).

I hope it helps and that I've been clear enough explaining my view :)

I would write:
    var agentModel = new AgentModel({SpecificAgentModelData(name,id...)});

And inside the init of AgentModel I'll get what's in agentCollections.

```
init: function({specificAgentModelData}) {
   set.thespecificThing;
   set.otherThingsfromAgentCollection(get.agentCollection...);
}
```

The principle is that you have 2 parts A and B, you set A and B first because they are basic data then you do the composition C = A + B
In this example C get A when instantiated new C({A}) and get B in its init but we could imagine you A & B separately and C get both in its init being a pure composition/abstraction/gathering of other tiniest entities. 
Sorry for the ugly pseudo code, is it clearer ?

Comment: Hey, so do you mean I set up an Agent Model and an Agents Collection then do something like var agentsCollection = new Agents({ collection: agentModel.get('agents') }); ? Not overly sure I know what you mean about building p the model though?

Comment: No I mean the contrary, if I understand well agentModel gathers agentsCollection data + other datas(id,name,location,city) so agentModel is a composition of agentsCollection + something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use backbone-relational which is a backbone plugin for defining complex model/collection hierarchies. You don't need to define simple properties, they will be automatically included in your model.

http://backbonerelational.org/

```
MyModel = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
relations: [{
    type: Backbone.HasMany,
    key: 'agents',
    relatedModel: 'Agent',
}]
});
```

key should be JSON key of array, relatedModel is your backbone model with attributed id,name and if you define type as Backbone.HasMany, then this will cast 'agents' into a collection.

Then `this.model.get('agents')` will give you a collection.